Is the integration variable a dummy variable?
I want to ask about terminology & notation.
Say we are having 3 functions, $f(x)$, $h(x)$, and $g(x)$ which are "implicitly known" to be related via the definite integral in the following manner:
$$f(x) = g(x) + \int_a^b h(x) dx$$
Given some constant, $c$, which of the following are correct:
$$f(c) = g(c) + \int_a^b h(c) dx$$
or
$$f(c) = g(c) + \int_a^b h(x) dx$$
What if those 3 functions, $f(x)$, $h(x)$, and $g(x)$ are "implicitly known" to be related via the indefinite integral in the following manner?
$$f(x) = g(x) + \int h(x) dx$$
would we then have
$$f(c) = g(c) + \int h(c) dx$$
or
$$f(c) = g(c) + \int h(x) dx$$

Note that $\int_a^b h(c)dx=h(c)(a-b)$ since $h(c)$ is a constant w.r.t $x$.

Having learned that we leave the indefinite integral as an exercse for you. Rigorous proof please. No symbol manipulation.

@BoweiTang that's all well and good, but does that mean that $c$ does get passed to $h(x)$ within the integral...?

@KurtG. are you talking to me? I don't understand your comment.

What do you mean by the equation with the indefinite integral? There's an arbitrary constant of integration in the value of the indefinite integral; how can the function $f(x)$ account for that?

@DavidK Which one? How would $f(x)$ not be able to account for a constant of integration? It's just a constant. There could be any constant within $f(x)$.

Sure, $f(x)$ can be any function you want, but one would assume that it is a particular function. On the other hand, $\int h(x),dx$ is not a function. It's a family of functions.

@DavidK Are you saying that it's incorrect? Cause I have no idea — that's why I'm here.

I'm saying it's not clear how to even interpret the second half of the question as a question. Putting a few symbols together doesn't always result in a statement.

@DavidK What about the first half?

Yet another reason to ditch the indefinite integral symbol altogether. It is a relic of the past and really confusing in modern mathematics.

Principle 1 : We use Dummy variable in "Definite Integration" :
$$I = \int_a^b h(x) dx \equiv \int_a^b h(y) dy \equiv \int_a^b h(z) dz\tag{P1}$$
Evaluating $I$ , that value will not have the Dummy variable at all. It is immaterial what we want use , except that we can not connect that variable to the "elements/world" outside that Integration.
Principle 2 : We do not use Dummy variable in "InDefinite Integration" :
$$I(x) = \int h(x) dx \not \equiv \int h(y) dy \not \equiv \int h(z) dz\tag{P2}$$
Evaluating $I(x)$ , we must get the value in terms of $x$ , not in terms of $y,z$
Here $x$ is not Dummy variable.

We are given :
$$f(x) = g(x) + \int_a^b h(x) dx\tag{BAD}$$
It is wrong to write that. The Integration uses a Dummy variable which clashes with the outside elements/world.
$$f(x) = g(x) + \int_a^b h(y) dy\tag{OKAY}$$
This is the way it should have been written , using the Dummy variable without clashes.
Still , we might accept that abuse of notation , at the moment , to check the variations given.
$$f(c) = g(c) + \int_a^b h(c) dx \tag{WRONG}$$
We are just integrating a Constant ! It will not give right value.
$$f(c) = g(c) + \int_a^b h(x) dx\tag{OKAY}$$
We have 3 Constants here , while Dummy variable $x$ is not clashing. It is okay here.

We are given :
$$f(x) = g(x) + \int h(x) dx\tag{CORRECT}$$
We are making a connection between 2 functions using the Integral , which is totally valid. We can not change the variable here , unless we change it though out.
$$f(c) = g(c) + \int h(c) dx\tag{WRONG}$$
We are integrating a Constant , losing the Original function. It will not give the right value.
$$f(c) = g(c) + \int h(x) dx\tag{WRONG}$$
We have 2 Constants with the last term involving $x$ : that is not what we want.
$$f(c) = g(c) + \left[\int h(x) dx\right]_{x=c}\tag{CORRECT}$$
We have 3 Constants with no term involving $x$ : that is what we want.
There are various notations like this. What it indicates is : Integrate the given term , then Evaluate it at the value $x=c$ , to give a Constant value.

$\int h(x),\mathrm dx$ is not a function so evaluating it at $x=c$ (among other things) does not really make sense.

To add to the previous comment: $f(x)$ is a single function whereas $g(x) + \int h(x), dx$ is a family containing infinitely many functions, so we need additional context to understand what we are saying when we put an $=$ symbol between these two things (and whether it even makes sense to write this equation). I would say that if you have a context where the first "correct" indefinite integral equation makes sense, then you should be able to make sense of the last indefinite integral equation, whereas the other two are definitely wrong (in agreement with this answer).

Yes , that was my vague thinking , that in certain (unknown) OP Contexts , all given functions have to go though $(0,0)$ , then those Integrals will not have variability in the Constant of Integration $C$ , then each Integration gives at most one "function" to make the first "Correct" Case , then when we evaluate that at $x=c$ , we get the last "Correct" Case , @DavidK , the other way I was thinking about it was : after we make those Equations using $C$ , OP will use Boundary Values or Initial Values to get the $C$ value. [[Cont]]

[[Cont]] One last way I thought about it was in terms of Integral Equations or Integro-Differential Equations. I avoided mentioning all that , @ultralegend5385 , thinking that it will make the answer cumbersome/confusing. OP has to justify what is given. Only then we can justify/reject the given alternatives here. When what is given is itself invalid , then all the variations are automatically invalid.

From the context of the OP, it seems the particular equation is less of interest than the question of how to interpret $\int h(x), dx$ when $x$ also appears outside the indefinite integral. The form of this equation obscures the actual question they wanted to ask. I think it was just an unfortunate choice of example.

Indeed , my Principle 1 + Principle 2 covers what OP actually wants to know , @DavidK , in the most general terms.

Note that $\int_a^bh(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is a fixed number, say $K$. Then, $f(x)=g(x)+K$ or $f(c)=g(c)+K$ both are fine. However, $\int_a^bh(c)\,\mathrm dx=h(c)(b-a)$ is not necessarily equal to $K$, so
$$f(x)=g(x)+\int_a^bh(c)\,\mathrm dx$$
does not hold necessarily. The indefinite integral equation does not make sense since $\int h(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is not a well-defined function (it has an arbitrary constant).
Hope this helps. :)
